# Uneven padding on the profile page

Tags: bug, design

Something that's been bothering my OCD for a while now are the sub tabs of the summary tab, at your profile page:
[image]

The `votes` tab here have a 4px padding at the bottom but a two pixel padding at the top. Is there a specifik reason for this? Otherwise you could change it to:

```
.subtabs a {
    ...
    padding: 2px 4px;
    //padding: 2px 4px 4px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it should be changed to `padding: 3px 4px` to preserve the same 6px overall padding and thus the size of the box. Otherwise it would look too small.

Comment: In addition to up- and down-vote buttons, we should have a "meh" or "too pedantic" vote. :-)

Comment: I don't know man... if you ask me `padding: 3px 4px` is the way to go.